# Prototyping board for the STM32F401RCT6?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, protoboard

I am new to this kind of thing, but I am trying to learn how to turn a prototyped circuit into a commercial board. To do this I have switched from Teensy over to ST's platform. However, with going from development to commercial I need a way to prototype Surface Mounted Devices (SMD) without, needing anything fancy or expensive. I looked around, but I couldn't find a Protoboard/MCUcard for my MCU, am I missing something or is there another way?

- MCU: STM32F401RCT6
- Package size: LQFP64

Comment: For ST there are Nucleo boards. You do not need to match package so much the since the internals are the same for different packages and the pinouts are easily re-assigned when you change to the same MCU in a different package. https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html

Comment: A nucleo board doesn't help me know my own prototyped MCU circuit works and is commercial ready right? I have already prototyped this project w/ Teesny's platform I am trying to switch over to prototyping for a PCB not to another ST development board.

Comment: But you can use the same argument for whether the PCB works, in which case you might as well make the PCB and test it.

Comment: Why would I make a PCB & pay to test it, before I prototype the PCB by hand to LEARN?

Comment: You'll find out soon enough.

Comment: That's not an answer

Comment: It is. I understand why you feel that way though. I used to think like you too. With a lot of digital circuits it's just about getting the point-to-point connections correct so often it isn't necessary to do a hand prototype. If you really want to prototype the bare MCU then you use dead bug methods which incidentally is what is required for analog.

Comment: So, it's cheaper to make a PCB and export the gerber to someone and test it then to buy things and hand prototype it?

Comment: How am I supposed to know my circuits even correct, before I pay someone alot of money to make me a pcb?

Comment: Often yes. Breakout boards can be very expensive and don't solve the inconvenience and error proneness of wiring up a bunch of digital connections by hand. I assume you want to do this because you're not super confident about the correctness of your wiring yet and I get that.

Comment: There are cheaper hobbiest/batch PCB services like OSH park. What you do is get a *tiny* (aka cheap) PCB made from such a service for just the MCU to test that you can interface with the MCU through a programmer. That's the critical part if you're unfamiliar with working with a bare MCU. Then you can make your entire PCB.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense actually! Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it cheap to have these small PCB's made or are we talking big money? (I know it's dependent on components)

Comment: At OSH Park, I believe it's $5 per square inch for 2-layers and you get 3 boards. I think $10 per square inch for 4 layer. The other hobby services should be somewhat similar. There are a few other hobby PCB services but I don't know their names off the top of my head. Search around. It's a much higher cost per area than normal service but the normal services have a much higher initial cost. So if you only need a few boards the hobby service is cheaper.

Comment: I will look around a bit for some service that do this. Is this sort of thing where I have to surface mount all of these components by hand after I get the PCB or do they do that to? I know some companies that do both, but I mean the cheap PCB providers you speak of.

Comment: The hobby services only make the PCB. The hobby services will batch your order with other orders into a big panel. That's how they reduce the expensive one-time setup cost. You'll want to learn how to solder surface mount by hand. It's not difficult. Drag solder. Get a needle bottle with flux or a flux pen. I recommend an 2-3mm oval bevel solder tip, and even better if only the face is tinned (no tinning on the sides). Turnkey services that also mount components (called assembling) are not for low quantities of boards. It will cost.

Comment: @DKNguyen : there are some "hobby services" that also do PCB assembly at low cost for single PCBs. For example, at JLCPCB (we use it at work, for simple, non critical PCBs with or without assembly, at quatities <=5), you can get PCB+assembly for <20$ for small PCBs. There are others with similar offers if I'm not mistaken. However, usually, you have to remain within a small size (5*5 or 10*10cm) and low complexity. If not, the price increases significantly.

Comment: @Sandro So no BGAs? Darn. Because that's the service you really need.

Comment: @DKNguyen : I haven't ordered any PCB with BGA from JLCPCB. But it seems that they still consider it ok for economic assembly : https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/pcb-assembly-capabilities . If you want to make sure, just do a simple PCB and get a quote. Note that at JLCPCB, they have a few hundred "standard" components always loaded in the pick and place machines that cost nearly nothing. For other components, there is a setup fee.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't waste time trying to get something like a LQFP-64 to DIP adapter.  At $16 a piece they're on par with just getting your own boards made, which is what I would recommend since you're going to have to make the jump sometime.  There's also "development boards" sold by ST that are kind of like Arduino modules.  They also come with schematics so you can make sure that you have everything designed correctly when it comes time to transfer over to your own board.

Comment: Does an "LQFP-64 to DIP adapter" exist for this? I only need this for prototyping the commercial board. I wouldn't be doing this with every single board.

Comment: Generic ones exist but you will probably run into problems with the external crystal (if you were using one) and it forces the power supply caps to be further away than is generally recommended.  My guess is it would cause more problems than it's worth.  You could design your own "carrier board", but at that point it's probably just worth it to get the dev board.  My recommendation is to consider this "revision 0" of your production board and design from scratch since it is unlikely that you will get it perfect the first time.  You can get a 2-layer board for ~$10 with a minimum quantity of 4.

Comment: I am doing that. I already started from scratch. I am here to learn how to prototype my pcb now that I have prototyped my circuit.

Comment: So, it's cheaper to make a PCB and export the gerber to someone and test it then to buy things and hand prototype it?

Comment: In short, yes.  PCB production prices have fallen dramatically in the past few years.  Hand prototyping is appropriate for testing certain parts of the circuit but the jump from breadboard (or whatever your test setup is) to working PCB will probably run into issues so you will very likely need to iterate your PCB design.  Even if everything works properly the first time, you'll see places where you could clean up the design here, add a feature there, etc.  Worst case scenario, you've validated your PCB design for less than $50 before pulling the trigger on a full production run.

Comment: I was thinking about this from a place of learning, but I get where y'all are coming from, now for sure!!